# Can you check my solution for this probability question?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

##### The question:

We have 6 mint and 6 lemon flavoured candies. The 12 candies are distributed randomly between Anne and Barbara, such that each girl gets 6 pieces. What is the probability that all the mint flavoured candies go to Anne?

##### The answer:

all cases: ${12\choose 6}$, because we choose 6 candies for Anne from total of 12 candies

good cases:  ${6\choose 6} $, because we choose 6 indistinguishable (order does not matter) mint candies from total of 6 mint candies.
$$\text{probability} = \frac{\text{good cases}}{\text{all cases}} $$
$$\text{probability} = \frac{6\choose6}{12\choose 6} $$
$$\text{probability}= \frac{1}{924}$$

##### The problem:

Is my logic right? If not, can you explain me where did I do wrong. Thank you

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seek the probability for Anne obtaining 6 from 6 mint candies when selecting 6 from 12 candies.

So indeed the probability is $\left.\tbinom 66\middle/\tbinom {12}6\right.$.